How to change vuetify expansion panel animation
I'm currently using Vuetify with chart.js I tried to implement a chart.js inside a v-expansion-panel :
          <v-expansion-panels class="my-4" variant="popout">
            <v-expansion-panel title="Item">
              <v-expansion-panel-text>
                <TrajectoryChart :trajectory="coloredLines"></TrajectoryChart>
              </v-expansion-panel-text>
            </v-expansion-panel>
          </v-expansion-panels>

But both animations are not working good together, I would like both animations working smoothly without any latency. I would like to change v-expansion-panel animation's behavior to not wait for his content to load to expand
Expansion not working
I've added a timeout to display my graph after 300ms which remove the latency
<template>
  <div v-if="showChart" id="chart-container" class="rounded pa-2 w-100">
    <canvas ref="chartCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="chart-container-substitute"></div>
</template>

... 

onMounted(async () => {
  showChart.value = true;
  await nextTick();
  setTimeout(() => {
    createChart();
  }, 300);
});

But the expansion is still done in two times but instead of this mini-useless first expansion :
First useless expansion animation
I would prefer that the expansion is done completly in one time.
Any idea how to solve this ?
